# update firebase web authentication user password

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

user's password won't change for some reason. here's what I'm working with:

```
function resetPass() {
    
    var email = document.getElementById("emailX").value;
    var oldpass = document.getElementById("oldpass").value;
    var newpass = document.getElementById("newpass").value;
  
    var cred = firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.credential(email, oldpass);
  
    auth.currentUser.reauthenticateWithCredential(cred)
        .then(() =>  console.log("Success: Authentication completed!"))
        .catch((er) => console.error("Error: " + er.message));
  
    auth.currentUser.updatePassword(newpass)
        .then(() => console.log("Success: Password is updated!"))
        .catch((err) => console.error("Error: Password updation failed. " + err.message));
  }
```

signing in works just fine but updating a user's password won't work.

Comment: `won't work` can you be more specific?  Errors?  Broken network requests?

Comment: literally nothing happens when I enter a user's email and their old password and then the new one, their password doesn't get updated, and no errors appear

Answer (score 0):

Calls to Firebase Authentication (like most cloud APIs) are asynchronous, and you need to wait for `reauthenticateWithCredential` to complete, before calling `updatePassword`.

So a simple fix:

```
auth.currentUser.reauthenticateWithCredential(cred)
    .then(() => {
        console.log("Success: Authentication completed!")
        auth.currentUser.updatePassword(newpass)
            .then(() => console.log("Success: Password is updated!"))
            .catch((err) => console.error("Error: Password updation failed. " + err.message));
    })
    .catch((er) => console.error("Error: " + er.message));
```

Or (a bit shorter) by letting the result bubble up:

```
auth.currentUser.reauthenticateWithCredential(cred)
    .then(() => {
        console.log("Success: Authentication completed!")
        return auth.currentUser.updatePassword(newpass);
    })
    .then(() => console.log("Success: Password is updated!"))
    .catch((er) => console.error("Error: " + er.message));
```

Comment: Still doesn't work for me :( , can I show you the html file and the javascript one incase the problem is somewhere else? Thank you for your time.

Comment: "Still doesn't work" is hard to help with. After reading my answer, does it make sense why your original code didn't work and why the chance I propose would remove that specific problem? --- If there are more problems, I recommend setting a breakpoint on each line of the code you shared, runnning in the debugger, and checking the value of each variable on each line. When you do that, what is the *first* line that doesn't do what you expect it to do?